# How to configure apache to serve already compressed files?

Tags: apache, apache2

I would like to know if it is possible to configure apache to deliver files that are already gzipped on the filesystem.

I mention that I want apache to deliver these files using HTTP compression protocol.

If this is possible it should work like this: A `file.txt.gz` is stored on the server and a client (supporting compression) makes a request for file `file.txt`, the server would send the compressed file to the client.

Answer (score 1):

According to the author of [this page](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2007/12/06/serve-pre-compressed-content-with-apache), you can serve your compressed files. First, add a type handler:

```
AddType "text/css;charset=UTF-8" .cssgz
AddEncoding gzip .cssgz
```

Then rewrite all requests for *.txt to *.txt.gz:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
RewriteRule (.*)\.txt$ $1\.txt.gz [L]
```